# Undefined while cast api response in any type in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to store data like this`public initData: any = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3'];`.
I am calling an API and It gives this response
[image]

I declare `private initData: any;` and after getting the response I try to store in that like this

```
this.userService.getUserRolesById(this.id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.initData = data.Name;
        console.log(this.initData);
})
```

### userservice

```
public getUserRolesById(id: number) {
    return this.httpHelper.get(this._getUserRolesByIdUrl+'?userId='+id)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Can you please add `userService.getUserRolesById` implementation?

Comment: code updated as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you get an array and you want a property in this array.

```
public initData:string[] = [];//Typing your arrays is important ;).
...
...
...
this.userService.getUserRolesById(this.id)
    .subscribe(roles => {
        roles.forEach(role => {
            console.log(role.Name);
            this.initData.push(role.Name);
        }
});
```

Comment: It works but one thing more I want to store it like this `public initData: any = ['Admin', 'Guest', 'Super Admin'];`

Comment: I added a push to the `initData` field.